# Does the new Brightcove player support timestamps in the scrubber

Tags: brightcove

We are in the process of switching over to the new HTML5 Brightcove player.  It seems to be working correctly with all of our preferred functionality.  However, when you hover over the scrubber there is no time tooltip, and we can find no way to restore this functionality.

Is it possible to get a hover tooltip on the scrubber of the new Brightcove player showing the time, and possibly a screenshot?

The code we're using to display the player is as follows:

```
 <video style='width:482px; height:392px; bgcolor:#FFFFFF;'
     id="BCvideoPlayer"
     data-video-id="#videoID#"
     data-account="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     data-player="default"
     data-embed="default"
     data-width="482"
     data-height="392"
     class="video-js" controls></video>
 <script src="//players.brightcove.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/default_default/index.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were informed by Brightcove support that this is not supported by the current player, but has been submitted as an enhancement requested.

In the mean time we have made this work using the following plugin: https://github.com/mickey/videojs-progressTips, though we had to modify one line of the file to account for the Brightcove changes to the underlying player:

```
    $("#vjs-tip").css("top", "" + (event.pageY - $(this).offset().top - barHeight - 25) + "px").css("left", "" + (event.pageX - $(this).offset().left + 125) + "px").css("visibility", "visible");
```